# Count number of pieces data is split to by a certain delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split, count, delimiter

Data looks like this:

```
Aaa, Bbb, Ccc, Ddd, Eee, Fff
Aaa, Bbb, Ccc, Ddd, Eee
Aaa, Bbb, Ccc, Ddd
Aaa, Bbb, Ccc
Aaa, Bbb
Aaa
```

Data in rows is split by the '**,**' delimiter. I want to get the number of parts that each row is split to.
Here is the figure:

[image]

So, in the 1st row the data is split to 6 parts by ',' delimiter. In the 2nd - 5 parts and so on.

What formula should I use is the column B?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd use this formula:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1
```

In case you need 0, when the cell is empty (the above formula returns 1), use this:

```
=IF(A1="",0,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1)
```